# Enable Samsung's "video enhancer" for arbitrary app

Tags: samsung, screen, video, samsung-galaxy-s7, screen-brightness

The Samsung S7, S8 and perhaps other phones have a "video enhancer" feature that can be turned on in the phone settings. This significantly improves visibility under strong lighting (outdoors) in those apps which it affects (YouTube, video player, etc.)  The screen appears much brighter than when manually set to maximum brightness.

Is there a way (or a hack) to force the video enhancer to activate for an arbitrary app?

There is an app that presents a live video feed and I frequently need to use it outdoors. The video enhancer would make a world of difference for this app, if only I could enable it.

Comment: Install [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sika524.android.quickshortcut) and see if you can launch a short cut to that feature. If you can it is easy to automate

Comment: @beeshyams I tried it, and while it reveals several otherwise not directly accessible features, the video enhancer does not seem to be there.  I tried or researched the ones which I was not familiar with—none of them are responsible for this effect.

Comment: This [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cygery.repetitouch.free) may be an option of your device is rooted

Comment: @beeshyams Interesting idea to try split-screen (even though the app I am interested in does not support that). It turns out that when using split-screen mode (or a floating window), the video enhancer is always off. As soon as I turn that off (e.g. close a floating window above the video), the feature activates.

Comment: I guess you will have to root and try the automation option or wait for a hack. There are more posts on disabling that feature. Guess Samsung has a lousy of apps to enable it for. You can probably ask on SO as to what triggers this feature. That may throw up some possibilities